CpiContext with_remaining_accounts is not working because of lifetimes
I'm writing a Solana program with Anchor 0.29.0 and Solana 1.18.9.
I want to invoke through CPI another program. It all worked well until I realised that, the called program needs the remaining accounts as well. And when I tried to pass them through the CpiContext I blocked into argument requires that '1 must outlive '2.
Here is my instruction file:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MyVaultExecuteTransaction<'info> {
    
    #[account(mut)]
    pub executor: Signer<'info>,

    pub my_config: Account<'info, MyConfig>,

    pub multisig: Account<'info, Multisig>,

    #[account(mut)]
    /// CHECK: Managed by Squads
    pub proposal: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// CHECK: Managed by Squads
    pub transaction: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub squads_multisig_program: Program<'info, SquadsMultisigProgram>,
}

impl MyVaultExecuteTransaction<'_> {
    fn validate(&self) -> Result<()> {
        let Self {
            my_config, executor, ..
        } = self;

        // creator
        require!(
            my_config.is_executor(executor.key()).is_some(),
            Errors::NotAnExecutorError
        );
        
        Ok(())
    }
 
    
    #[access_control(ctx.accounts.validate())]
    pub fn handle(ctx: Context<MyVaultExecuteTransaction>) -> Result<()> {
    
        let vault_transaction_execute_cpi_accounts = VaultTransactionExecute {
            multisig: ctx.accounts.multisig.to_account_info(),
            proposal: ctx.accounts.proposal.to_account_info(),
            transaction: ctx.accounts.transaction.to_account_info(),
            member: ctx.accounts.executor.to_account_info(),
        };

        squads_multisig_program::cpi::vault_transaction_execute(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.squads_multisig_program.to_account_info(),
                vault_transaction_execute_cpi_accounts
            ).with_remaining_accounts(ctx.remaining_accounts.to_vec())
        )?;
    
        Ok(())
    }

}

and here is the error I get:
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> programs/my-sol/src/instructions/multisig_vault_execute_tx.rs:62:13
   |
46 |       pub fn handle(ctx: Context<MyVaultExecuteTransaction>) -> Result<()> {
   |                     ---
   |                     |
   |                     has type `anchor_lang::context::Context<'_, '_, '_, '1, multisig_vault_execute_tx::MyVaultExecuteTransaction<'_>>`
   |                     has type `anchor_lang::context::Context<'_, '_, '_, '_, multisig_vault_execute_tx::MyVaultExecuteTransaction<'2>>`
...
62 | /             CpiContext::new(
63 | |                 ctx.accounts.squads_multisig_program.to_account_info(),
64 | |                 vault_transaction_execute_cpi_accounts
65 | |             ).with_remaining_accounts(ctx.remaining_accounts.to_vec())
   | |_____________^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`

Appreciate your feedback!

I'm no rust expert but have been struggling with a similar issue.
Seems it's not happy with one lifetime outliving the other.
You can probably fix this by setting the lifetimes to be equal on your context.
pub fn handle<'info>(ctx: Context<'_, '_, '_, 'info, MyVaultExecuteTransaction<'info>>) -> Result<()> {
   ...
}


I think you are right!

And for more clarity, will continue here!
So, here is a working code, passing the remaining accounts for a CPI burn cNFT invocation. Please consider that all lifetime annotations are important for the code to compile.
I'll paste the entire instruction for simplicity, so please ignore everything else unrelated to our issue.
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use mpl_bubblegum::instructions::BurnCpiBuilder;

use crate::common::*;


#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct DCBurnArgs {
  pub root: [u8; 32],
  pub data_hash: [u8; 32],
  pub creator_hash: [u8; 32],
  pub leaf_index: u32,
  pub nonce: u64,

  pub leaf_id: Pubkey,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(args: DCBurnArgs)]
pub struct DCBurn<'info> {

  /// CHECK: Safe. Tree config.
  pub tree_config: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  /// CHECK: Safe. Merkle Tree
  #[account(mut)]
  pub merkle_tree: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  #[account(mut)]
  pub leaf_owner: Signer<'info>,
    
  /// CHECK. Safe.
  pub leaf_delegate: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  // #[account(mut)]
  // pub payer: Signer<'info>,

  /// CHECK: Safe. Bubblegum program.
  #[account(address = bubblegum_program_id::ID)]
  pub mpl_bubblegum_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  /// CHECK: Safe. Compression program.
  #[account(address = compression_program_id::ID)]
  pub spl_compression_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  /// CHECK: Safe. Log wrapper program.
  pub log_wrapper_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,

}

impl DCBurn<'_> {

  pub fn handler<'info>(ctx: Context<'_, '_, '_, 'info, DCBurn<'info>>, args: DCBurnArgs) -> Result<()> {
    
    let _ = BurnCpiBuilder::new(&ctx.accounts.mpl_bubblegum_program)
    // Merkle Tree
    .tree_config(&ctx.accounts.tree_config)
    .merkle_tree(&ctx.accounts.merkle_tree)

    // NFT 
    .leaf_owner(&ctx.accounts.leaf_owner, true)
    .leaf_delegate(&ctx.accounts.leaf_delegate, false)

    // Merkle retrieval
    .root(args.root)
    .data_hash(args.data_hash)
    .creator_hash(args.creator_hash)
    .nonce(args.nonce)
    .index(args.leaf_index)

     // Program
    .log_wrapper(&ctx.accounts.log_wrapper_program)
    .system_program(&ctx.accounts.system_program)
    .compression_program(&ctx.accounts.spl_compression_program)
    
    // Remaining accounts
    .add_remaining_accounts(ctx.remaining_accounts
      .iter()
      .map(|account| (account, false, false))
      .collect::<Vec<_>>()
      .as_slice())
    
    // invoke
    .invoke();
    
    Ok(())
  }
}

My code is based of the example I've found here https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/compression/cnft-burn/anchor/programs/cnft-burn/src/lib.rs
